# How to find particular contents in list of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Please can someone tell how to find particular pattern in list of files.
I use the command:

```
dir *.txt /b /s >> C:\Users\Amrendra\Downloads\NIT_Testing\fileList.txt
```

In `fileList.txt` I have a list of files.
Now I want to find a certain pattern say `abc` in all the files listed.
So I want each line containing that pattern to be written into a new file.

Please suggest as I am completely new to batch command.

Thanks

Comment: For a simple literal search string you could use `find "abc" fileList.txt`; another option is `findstr` which allows to use simple regular expressions too; type `find /?` or `findstr /?` for details; note that you can pipe your `dir` output into `find` or `findstr`, so you'd have `dir *.txt /b /s | find /i "abc"`; the optional `/i` switch makes the search case-insensitive; of course you can still redirect the output of this command line into a file...

Comment: The command does not work. Individually works but not together. `find /i "abc" <Src.txt >>Content.txt`
I am trying to make .bat file.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: It doesn't display any output when I use your command `dir *.txt /b /s | find /i "abc" >>List.txt`. Even though files contain `abc`. If I use `find` command individually on a single file, it works. I have a huge list of files. So I want all such patterns in all these files into a single file. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: `findstr /F:"C:\Users\Amrendra\Downloads\NIT_Testing\fileList.txt" /C:"abc"`

Comment: @JosefZ : Your command works the way I needed.

Comment: Ah, so you want to find the pattern in all the files listed in `fileList.txt` rather than the list file itself... I edited the question to clarify the intent...

Comment: @aschipfl : Yes, correct. Sorry if my question confused you. JosefZ solution worked. Thanks

Comment: Okay... so the new file should contain every *line* throughout all listed files that contain the pattern?? I think @MichaelS' solution returns a list of *files* that contain the pattern... please clarify the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you completely right. You've echoed the names of all .txt files from some folder into one text file. Now you want to check it line by line for filenames containing some substring in the file name. Is that correct? If it is, here is the solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET targetFile=C:\Some\Path\SomeTextFile.txt
SET sourceFile=C:\Some\Path\Source.txt
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TYPE NUL>%targetFile%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (sourceFile) DO (
    SET templine=%%L
    SET templine=!templine:abc=!
    IF NOT !templine!==%%L (
        ECHO %%L>>%targetFile%
    )
)
```

Let's take a look on how it works: first we put the path to the file containing the file names into the variable `%sourceFile%` and the path to the target file into the variable `%targetFile%`. We need `EnableDelayedExpansion` to be able to work with changing variables inside the FOR-loop. `TYPE NUL>%targetFile%` simply clears the target file in case there are some entries from former runs.

The main work is done inside the FOR-loop. We read the source file line by line and want to check if the line contains the substring we are looking for. To do this we first store the line (`%%L`) in a temporary variable. Then we replace any occurrences of the search string with an empty string, means we simply remove abc from the temporary string. Finally we compare our modified temporary string with the original one. If they are equal we can be sure that the serch string `abc` was not in the original string. The other way around, if the strings differ, the substring was in the original string. So in the second case we do `ECHO %%L>>%targetFile%` which means we write the whole file name containing the search substring into our target file. Et voilà, we're done!

**EDIT:** As you want to search all listed files for the substring, here the new code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET sourceFile=C:\Users\Amrendra\Downloads\NIT_Testing\fileList.txt
SET targetFile=C:\Users\Amrendra\Downloads\NIT_Testing\newList.txt
SET searchString=abc
TYPE NUL>%targetFile%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%sourceFile%) DO (
    FINDSTR %searchString% "%%L">NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==0 ECHO %%L>>%targetFile%
)
```

Here we are using `findstr` to check if a text file contains the string we are searching. As `findstr` usually would output the line which contains the searched string (which we don't want) we simply mute the command using `>NUL`. What we actually need is the `ERRORLEVEL`! If the string was found in a file `findstr` will set `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 or to 1 otherwise. So the only thing we have to do is to check if `!ERRORLEVEL!==0`.

Comment: I want to find the patterns in the contents of listed files. I mean if there 10 files that has been listed, I want to find the pattern in all these files. And then I want that all those lines to be written into a new file.